# "For each" in VBA - looks like code execute task twice

Tags: excel, vba, foreach

I would like to create TAB that contains all charts from the workbook. I created a code for active sheet and it works. When I wanted to create a loop for all tabs then looks like it is being executed twice. I tried to debug but I don't see where is the problem.

```
Sub LoopOver()
    Dim xSh As Worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each xSh In Worksheets
        xSh.Select
        Call ChartSelector
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub ChartSelector()

Dim mychart As ChartObject


For Each mychart In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
    mychart.Copy
    Sheets("Consolidated").Paste
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Exclude the consolidated sheet from your loop if it exists already

Comment: You were right. Thank you - now each chart was copied once.